# How to automatically update a local repository after another repository pushes to remote?

Tags: git, push, auto-update

I have N+2 repositories in drive E:

1. Test_central - central repository;
2. Test_primary1 - local repository;
3. Test_primaryN - local repository;
4. Test_slave - local repository.

How can I update Test_slave when Test_primaryI has pushed its own changes to Test_central?

P.S.: all repositories on one drive only for testing

Comment: Isn't that N+2 repositories? Just saying!

Comment: what's the difference? logic of this does not change, but thanks for the correction

Comment: I know. Just couldn't resist saying that ;)

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to hook into one of the available hooks in the `Test_slave` repo.  Have a look [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).  It's as simple as writing a script to do what you want, giving it the correct name in the `.git/hooks` folder, and making it executable.

To make things nice and easy, example scripts are already provided in the `hooks` folder.  Just remove the `.sample` extension from the `.sample` file for hook you'd like to use, and then edit the script to suit your needs.

Comment: Note that you'll need to put the hook in the initial recieving repository, `Test_central` or the sending repository `Test_primaryX`. You can't put them in `Test_slave` - as pushing from `Test_primary` to `Test_central` will never touch `Test_slave` and so it wont know to fire any of its hooks.

Comment: I tried to change the hook post-update.sample for Test_central, but nothing has happened. Script: 

#!/bin/sh
cd e:\Test_slave\ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

exec git-update-server-info